# Spring java configuration doesn't find a bean which has been created through context:component-scan

Tags: spring, jax-rs

I have so far mixed xml and java configurations with very good success, but there is a use case which seems not to work.
I let spring configure my JAX-RS resources using component scan and they are correctly resolved:

```
<context:component-scan
    base-package="<my packages>">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation"
        expression="javax.ws.rs.Path" />
...
```

But if I try to call one of those classes in my java config:

```
HttpInvokerServiceExporter exp = new HttpInvokerServiceExporter();
exp.setService(context.getBean(Users.class));
```

I get this error:
No unique bean of type [com.gecod.allianz.arco.web.restresources.Users] is defined: expected single bean but found 0:

One solution could be to declare JAX-RS bean in xml or java configuration, but this way Resteasy doesn't recognize them as JAX-RS resources.

I think I have a race condition, any hints?

Comment: Which context are you using to perform the lookup? There's a chance it could be the wrong one.

Comment: context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");

Note that context:component-scan is in that xml config file.
thank you

Comment: I just tried: it doesn't work in web context either (that snippet was from the test case code)

Comment: Maybe try and put a breakpoint in `http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-context/3.1.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java#78` (or similar) and see which context the beans are being put in, then compare this to the context used by your code? Maybe also turn on info/debug logging for the `org.springframework.context.annotation` package?

Comment: thanks, this helped me to get it to work, but I am even more puzzled: the bean actually is in the context, but it is only recognized by name (which is default so I don't like it very much) and not by class...

Answer (score 0):

see if this works better

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"       xsi:schemaLocation="        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">            <context:annotation-config />    
<context:component-scan base-package="com.blah.blah" />
```

Comment: I am no longer on that project, but thanks anyway for your suggestion; if I recall correctly components were scattered across different packages, that's why I used the annotation approach.